# Remove white background from an image

Tags: background, imagemagick, image-manipulation, perlmagick

I want to get a transparent background or no background for my images. I tried the '-background none' option and also the 'transparent' option, but  the background image remains white. How can I achieve this?

Please suggest.

Comment: Probably need more info. Are you asking how to create a transparent GIF or PNG? Or how to make images have transparency in some development or HTML environment? Or?

Comment: does your image have a white background by any chance?

Comment: I have a png image with pure white background. My aim is to superimpose this image(without any background) onto another image. The problem I am facing is  that the white background is also superimposed onto the image while doing so.

Comment: Yes, it shows a white background even though I create none.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11509894

Answer (score 20):

If you are using Imagemagik then the command is:

```
convert input.gif -transparent white output.gif
```

However, it will only work with a pure white background and not a shade of white.
There are alternative and easier ways to do this with IrfanView or The Gimp or Photoshop (more on that below).
This article mentions that you may be using `convert.exe` that comes with Windows rather than `ImageMagicks Convert.exe` in which case you should use the full path for  `Convert.exe`.
http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10665

If you are trying to achieve this from CSS then you misunderstand the CSS property.
The css property 'background' refers to an html elements background color. I.e.  `<p> <div> <body>` whatever.
more here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

If you are referring to the image opacity property, that refers to how "see-through" an image should be. more here:
http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp

The only way to get a transparent background in an image is to make the background of the image transparent using either the `PNG` (preferred) or `GIF` formats. For this you can use `IrfanView` and save a picture as `PNG`, select the "save transparency" property and select the color from the image you want to be transparent or you can use Photoshop or The Gimp do the same. Example for `IrfanView` here http://llizard.etherwork.net/cwc/transp_irfanview.html

The Gimp example here http://aplawrence.com/Linux/crousegif.html

Answer (score -1):

whats the format of your images? Try using png format

Comment: I am using png format.Even tried creating some basic shapes in imagemagick, but a white circum-rectangle is always created though I set the background to none.