# ImageMagick - How do I flatten white levels to pure white?

Tags: imagemagick, transparent, levels, threshold

I have a png image with a white background which I'd like to turn transparent. This is [fairly simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5230125/187907) with this command:

```
$ convert image.png -transparent white image-trans.png
```

However, if the white background is not completely white (i.e, `#FFFFFF`, `rgb(255,255,255)`, etc), then this doesn't work well.

Is there a way to set reduce everything below a certain threshold to complete white? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The commandline option you are looking for is

```
-white-threshold value{%}
```

So a command of

```
convert image.png \
  -white-threshold 90% \
  -transparent white \
   image-trans.png
```

**Note:** Order of the respective parameters is significant! (You want first to convert all the light-gray pixels to white, then all white pixels to transparent.)

Works for me with *'ImageMagick version 6.7.8-0 2012-07-12 Q16'*...